C# Single NetworkStream creates both Reader and Writer, are they independent?
Until now I've had no dealing with NetworkStream and am having to use it for some TCP comms with a tcp enabled device, but I'm seeing some strange behaviour and it's got me asking the question above...
I create the TCPClient and connect to a TCPServer that is constantly broadcasting it's live data. I can also send it a data frame requesting it returns a specific piece of data.
So my basic loop code looks like this:
using (_stream = _tcpClient.GetStream())
using (_streamReader = new StreamReader(_stream))
using (_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_stream) { AutoFlush = true })
{
    if (_cancellationTokenSource != null)
    {
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        var cancellationTask = cancellationToken.AsTask();
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var messageTask = _streamReader.ReadMessageAsync();
            await Task.WhenAny(messageTask, cancellationTask);

            if (messageTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                InvokeMessageReceivedEvent(messageTask.Result);
            }

            if (cancellationTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                InvokeConnectionEvent("Listening Stopped");
            }
        }
    }
}

The _streamReader.ReadMessageAsync() is an extension method, and reads the data frames nicely, allowing me to process incoming data easily.
I then use the _streamWriter to send messages to the TCPServer like this:
public async Task SendMessageAsync(string message)
{
    if(_streamWriter != null) { await _streamWriter.WriteAsync(message); }
}

Now I don't have much visibility into what the other device is doing, but it's not very powerful and has a cycle time of 10ms, eg it can process a single message in a cycle.
So here comes the crux of the matter. I'm sure that I'm reading messages I've just put into the _streamWriter!? EG Write message {Request=DataPoint123} with _streamWriter, then when I use the _streamReader I get {Request=DataPoint123} rather than the response {DataPoint123=7.654}.
Are they actually using the same stream? So if I read the _streamReader reads before the device gets to its read event in its cycle, it won't see the message I've just sent, as I've read it out of the NetworkStream?
Originally Not Included
public static Task AsTask(this CancellationToken @this)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    @this.Register(() => tcs.SetResult());
    return tcs.Task;
}


From the code provided it is hard to say where the problem is, _streamWriter is not used here.

No _streamWriter is not used in the listening loop, as it's used elsewhere to request specific information rather than listen to the broadcast frames. The main loop will the receive the response frame and process.

So, third using line above the listening loop, is redundant, correct? For the subject: is it reproduced even with the first single message? Could it be, that device just works in the echo mode? You have to know exact protocol - exact steps that are done on the server side.

I don't believe that the problem is with the NetworkStream sharing - it must support full duplex communication, ie sending data simultaneously in both directions. It is okay to read/write to it concurrently.

Btw - var cancellationTask = cancellationToken.AsTask(); - interesting Exceptionless pattern is used here.

@Ryan You're right, as the 3rd using item is never used in the loop. I just assign it at that point because then I know I have a valid stream I can use.

@Ryan It's from this extension method (I would give credit to whom originally wrote it, but I can't find it at the moment) - I'll add it to the original text.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

NetworkStream is full duplex, the read and write are completely independent. What does ReadMessageAsync do, and what exactly are you seeing that is causing an issue? By the way, it looks like you are leaking CTS registrations without disposiing them.

@Charlieface yes, I think you're right about the leak... More work required.

The linked answer did make me push the investigation of the device on the other side of the TCP comms. The TCP server has/had an error and was sending back messages I had sent, hence my original question. Thanks guys.
